# I need to add a wait till i get a response from angular http request with selenium-java

Tags: java, angularjs, http, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am very new to selenium , i am trying to write a code which will login into my website and check for the dropdowns and click on the button.
once after clicking the button a http angular request is fired and result is displayed. my requirement is to wait for the response and check the response with selenium and then logout from my website

```
    driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("https://url");
    driver.findElement(By.id("userId")).sendKeys("USERID");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("PASSWORD");
    driver.findElement(By.id("Submit")).click();

    Select dropdownA = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("mySelectA")));
    dropdownA.selectByValue("2");
    Select dropdownB = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("mySelectB")));
    dropdownB.selectByValue("5");

    driver.findElement(By.id("findroute")).click();

    /***/Here i need to wait for the angular http request to reply and check for the data displayed***

    driver.findElement(By.id("userTemp")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Logout")).click();
    driver.close();
```

Comment: You specified the requirement. What is your question?

Comment: i need to wait for the angular http request to reply and check for the data displayed . the data will be displayed in a Table structure on the HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Firstly,** lets add some implicit wait after initiating the driver. Now this is the default time selenium waits for any element including angular.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Now lets consider element A appears after some action performed by the user. Element A is angular i mean. Now check for the existence of the element.

```
driver.findElement(By.id(""));  
//Perform the required operations  after finding the element
```

The script waits for 60 seconds for the angular element to appear. If now we will be getting element not found exception.

**Secondly,**, we can make use of Explicit wait to achieve the same.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id<locator>));
```

or

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id<locator>));
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Comment: What if the response will not come in timeoutInSeconds , should i keep it to 60
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);

Comment: yes.. you can increase the time. Implicit wait will be default for all elements but webdriver wait is applicable one for that particular element.